# How to turn an exam document into a beamer document?

Tags: beamer, exam

I have the following example exam document, and I would like to turn it into a beamer representation such that each question has its own page in the beamer presentation (so I can go over it one by one). Is that possible?
Trying to change {exam} to {beamer} and keep the rest the same of course doesn't work because the different commands are not identified. Maybe there is something in between?

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question

Question 1

\begin{choices}

\item answer 1

\item answer 2

\item answer 3

\item answer 4

\end{choices}

\question    Question 2

\begin{choices}

\item answer 1

\item answer 2

\item answer 3

\item answer 4

\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really automatic (you still have to insert frame environments around your questions), but you can mimic the commands from the `exam` class:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{points}
\newenvironment{choices}{\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{questions}{\setcounter{points}{0}}{}
\newcommand{\question}[1][1]{\addtocounter{points}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question

\begin{frame}{Question 1}

\begin{choices}

\item answer 1

\item answer 2

\item answer 3

\item answer 4

\end{choices}
\end{frame}

\question[42]    
\begin{frame}{Question 2}

\begin{choices}

\item answer 1

\item answer 2

\item answer 3

\item answer 4

\end{choices}
\end{frame}

\end{questions}

\begin{frame}
Total number of points: \thepoints
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```